# Unable to set specific property of PageSetup

Tags: vba, excel

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = Cells(1, 1).Resize(LR, 16).Address
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FitToPagesWide = True
    .FitToPagesTall = False
End With
```

All properties are accepted **except** `.FitToPagesWide`

I get RT1004 - Unable to set property of the PageSetup class ONLY for this parameter.

All other properties are set correctly and operate as expected when I actually print the sheet.   I have another program that uses the same code block, and it works properly on several computers.

Comment: [from here:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-fittopageswide-property-excel) "If the `PageSetup.Zoom` property is True , the FitToPagesWide property is ignored." So maybe try setting `.Zoom` to false right above the line you're getting an error on?

Comment: `FitToPagesWide` is a tricky one. Its value can either be a pozitiv integer or `False` (=reset). Definitely not 0, negativ or `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
 Application.PrintCommunication = False
```

before setting the print parameters, then

```
 Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

after they're finished.   This prevents the error, and the print area is properly set and properly prints when tested - with the area fit to page width of whatever printer you use.

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure you have selected default printer. If you have no printer selected, you will also get an error.